# Add zeros after decimal marker

Tags: tables, siunitx

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareSIUnit\kroner{kr.}

\newcommand*\skyld[1]{
  \calc{((1+\rente)^(#1)*(\rente*\start-\afbetaling)+\afbetaling)/\rente}
}


\begin{document}

\def\start{612600}
\def\afbetaling{68199}
\def\rente{0.02}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format = 2]
  S[table-format = 6.2, round-mode = places, round-precision = 2]
}
 \toprule
  {$n$} & {$X(n)$}       \\
  {---} & {\si{\kroner}} \\
 \midrule
   0 & \skyld{ 0} \\
   1 & \skyld{ 1} \\
   2 & \skyld{ 2} \\
   3 & \skyld{ 3} \\
   4 & \skyld{ 4} \\
   5 & \skyld{ 5} \\
   6 & \skyld{ 6} \\
   7 & \skyld{ 7} \\
   8 & \skyld{ 8} \\
   9 & \skyld{ 9} \\
  10 & \skyld{10} \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I add `00` as decimals to the first two numbers in the second column? (I know that the two numbers are integers but I would like two decimals nonetheless.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `round-integer-to-decimal`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareSIUnit\kroner{kr.}

\newcommand*\skyld[1]{
  \calc{((1+\rente)^(#1)*(\rente*\start-\afbetaling)+\afbetaling)/\rente}
}


\begin{document}

\def\start{612600}
\def\afbetaling{68199}
\def\rente{0.02}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format = 2]
  S[table-format = 6.2, round-integer-to-decimal, round-mode = places, round-precision = 2]
}
 \toprule
  {$n$} & {$X(n)$}       \\
  {---} & {\si{\kroner}} \\
 \midrule
   0 & \skyld{ 0} \\
   1 & \skyld{ 1} \\
   2 & \skyld{ 2} \\
   3 & \skyld{ 3} \\
   4 & \skyld{ 4} \\
   5 & \skyld{ 5} \\
   6 & \skyld{ 6} \\
   7 & \skyld{ 7} \\
   8 & \skyld{ 8} \\
   9 & \skyld{ 9} \\
  10 & \skyld{10} \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]